Error CS2006: Command-line syntax error: Missing '<text>' for '-define:' option when installing URP in Unity 2021.3.15f1c1
I encountered the following error when installing URP into an existing project:
error CS2006: Command-line syntax error: Missing '<text>' for '-define:' option

I couldn't find any solutions online. Has anyone experienced the same issue?
Unity Version: 2021.3.15f1c1
I created a new empty project and installed URP without encountering the above issue. I hope someone can provide the cause of the problem and how to resolve it.

Any hint on where exactly this error comes from? Or is this actually all that appears in the console?

yes, this is actually all that appears in the console.

Do you have any custom define symbols or custom commandline arguments in your project settings? Maybe what i entered in the custom define symbols field is incorrectly formatted. This error occures because Unity is calling the compiler to compile the scripts and there seems to be an issue with the arguments that Unity passes to the compiler.

I have set custom define symbols, but this error was not reported before installing URP.
